# Modified WPFToolkit and now it doesn't work on every computer

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

We have to make a modification on the WPFToolkit.dll to add some watermark text. Now, when we install it on some computers (I can't find what's different about them), I get this

> Could not load file or assembly 'WPFToolkit, Version=3.5.40128.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)  Error in markup file
>   'MaintenanceDIRECTE;component/menuprincipal.xaml'.

The last part  (the name of xaml file) is the main form and use the watermark at some point.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening, i.e. force them to use the one we provide ?

Thanks

Comment: This might be a lame question, but are you sure you are using the correct framework versions?

Comment: Yes I am... The thing is we delibiratly modify it because we needed to change something but didn't change any assembly info. we're actually going to try changing the version number see if it solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the answer was simply to change the version number so that it won't be recognize as the same and therefore won't cause this problem...